# Equations in two columns and in box does not look too good

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, two-column, box

First of all, let see what I want. It is the two upper box with two equations in each.

[image: two boxes]

and the two boxes at the bottom are what I get from the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\author{Mario Lemelin}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\boxed{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\textcolor{Red}{\widetilde{\vec{e_j}}} &= \sum_{i} F_{i j} \, \textcolor{blue}{\vec{e_i}}  \\
\textcolor{blue}{\vec{e_j}} &= \sum_{i} B_{i j} \, \textcolor{Red}{\widetilde{\vec{e_i}}}
\end{array}
}
\columnbreak
\boxed{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\textcolor{Red}{\widetilde{\epsilon^i}} &= \sum_{i} B_{i j} \, \textcolor{blue}{\epsilon^j}  \\
\textcolor{blue}{\epsilon^i} &= \sum_{i} F_{i j} \, \textcolor{Red}{\widetilde{e^j}}
\end{array}
}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

So the line needs to be thicker. Also the summation should have the "i" below the summation sign.

Note that I am working with TexMaker under Win 11.

Comment: `array` is for matrices/arrays and makes inline math, which is why the summations are not in display style, use `aligned` from `amsmath` instead.

Answer (score 4):

As @DavidCarlisle has already suggested in a comment, use `aligned`, not `array`, environments.

I would also use `\mathcolor`, not `\textcolor`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % for '\mathcolor' macro
%\usepackage{multicol} % no longer needed

\begin{document}

\[
\boxed{%
\begin{aligned}
\mathcolor{Red}{\widetilde{\vec{e}}_j} &= \sum_{i} F_{ij} \, \mathcolor{blue}{\vec{e}_i}  
\\[\jot]
\mathcolor{blue}{\vec{e}_j} &= \sum_{i} B_{ij} \, \mathcolor{Red}{\widetilde{\vec{e}}_i}
\end{aligned}
}
\qquad
\boxed{%
\begin{aligned}
\mathcolor{Red}{\tilde{\epsilon}^i} &= \sum_{i} B_{ij} \, \mathcolor{blue}{\epsilon^j}  
\\[\jot]
\mathcolor{blue}{\epsilon^i} &= \sum_{i} F_{ij} \, \mathcolor{Red}{\tilde{e}^j}
\end{aligned}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response. I have two questions about the codes. When I run the compilation, I receive an error: " ! Argument of \token_if_expandable:NTF has an extra }.\end{aligned}} I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything." It seems like its the } after \end{aligned}, the one that close the \boxed{%. The software seems to see it glue to \end{aligned}. And that lead me to the seconde question. What is the use of the "%" in \boxed{%?

Comment: @M.Lemelin - Which of the two instances of `\end{aligned}` is causing a problem on your system? (Note also that both `aligned` environments are enclosed in `\boxed` macros.) Incidentally, which TeX distribution do you employ, and when was it last updated? FWIW, I use `MacTeX2024`, `LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1`, and `amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o`, and I experience no problems compiling my code under either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Regarding your second question: the `%` symbol is the basic comment character for TeX and LaTeX. Its use after `\boxed{` is optional.

Comment: finally found that it was not `\boxed{` that was the problem but `\mathcolor` and `{Red}`. I removed the `[dvipsnames]` and wrote only `\color` then replaced the `{Red}` by `{red}` and then everything worked. I am using MikTex 4.11 since I am under Win11. Thank you very much for your help Mico. Now I have what I wanted.

Comment: @M.Lemelin - Thanks for your follow-up reply. Indeed, `\mathcolor` requires a fairly up to date (ca 2022 or more recent) version of the `xcolor` package. About `Red` -- I copied that straight from your code; I agree that `red` is safer.